# java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: java, android

Merging Errors: 
Error: tools:replace specified at line:9 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 8 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.lsa.lgu.lsa">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".GroupChatActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you'll find it's a library you've imported, kindly share your app level build.gradle file. Another case this occurs is if you are migrating to AndroidX but you haven't correctly configured it in your gradle.properties. I both cases sharing the app level build.gradle can help in finding a solution

Answer (score -1):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lsa.lgu.lsa"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
}
```